# Chart.js: show tooltip color square only for certain row

Tags: chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

Is it possible to show the tooltip square only in one (certain) row?

Now it just duplicates color square for each line:

[image]

The goal is to add square only to first line "metric_val" to make it like that:

[image]

I tried `labelColor` `callback` but looks like it does not work in that way (it manipulates squares that appears in each row).

Answer (score 2):

Text **with** colored square should be in `label`

Text **without** colored square should be in `footer`:

```
tooltips: {
  callbacks: {
    footer: function(tooltipItems, data) {
      return ['Description 1', 'Description 2'];
    }
  }
}
```